# What is the best approach to reuse multiple repository criterias?

Tags: java, jpa, repository, criteria

I have an repository layer that have many methods combination, to match search criterias.. What is the best approach to reuse this criterias? I think that methods name like findByNameAndIdAndBirthdayAndAccounaNumber is not a good idea ! Thanks !

```
public Order findByIdAndName(String orderId) {
List<OrderEntity> list = entityManager.createNamedQuery(OrderEntity.QUERY_FIND_BY_ORDERID_AND_NAME,     OrderEntity.class)
     .setParameter("orderId", orderId)
     .setParameter("name", name).getResultList();
if (list.isEmpty()) {
    return null;
}

OrderEntity orderEntity = list.get(0);

return toOrder(orderEntity);
```

}

Comment: There is nothing wrong with those names. You still need to define those queries using na,e,id,birthday and account parameters. If it is annoys you, you can use the CriteriaBuilder and construct the queries from the parameter list/map...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you may be looking for the Specification pattern which would allow you write a method like:

```
public Order findOrderBySpecification(Specification specification) {

}
```

and then call this using a combination of one or more specifications e.g. by account number, by account number and name etc.

There is an example here using the Criteria API:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-using-specification

See also the article below which refers to the Spring Data project but which is probably worth a read anyway even if you are not using Spring.

http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Also, you can achieve this more simply using the QueryDSL library referenced in the article above rather than the rather verbose Criteria API with Straight JPA (i.e. without Spring).

http://blog.mysema.com/2010/04/querydsl-as-alternative-to-jpa-2.html
http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.0/reference/html/ch02s02.html

Comment: Alan judging by your reputation you are experienced developer, so I have a question. Have you used it in real stituation? Is it actually more managable than explicit JPA queries? You can check those one line queries by quick look at them, while with specification you need to open X classes and check their code (which most likely contain typical bugs induced by Ctr+C Ctr+V). Just your opinion/experience?

Comment: Given the choice I would use QueryDSL. I have been working with Hibernte/JPA for 7 or 8 years and have the Oracle JPA cert. Even if we ignore specifications for now, I find the Criteria API hideous. Would I rather use the Criteria API or do: List<User> users = repository.findAll(QUser.user.address.town.eq("London").and(QUser.user.gender.eq(Gender.M)))  and X and Y and Z... in any combination; I use it in personal projects and next time I'm on a Greenfield project for work would definately suggest it is considered.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Criteria/Specification approach vs JPQL query (text or named). But you already expresses your dislike to Criteria so I guess I know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the specification pattern in your repository implementation.

OrderSpecificationByName.java

```
public class OrderSpecificationByName implements OrderSpecification, HibernateSpecification {
    private String name;

    public OrderSpecificationByName(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfiedBy(Object order) {
        return ((Order)order).hasName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Criterion toCriteria() {
        return Restrictions.eq("name", name);
    }
}
```

OrderSpecificationById.java

```
public class OrderSpecificationById implements OrderSpecification, HibernateSpecification { 
    private Long id;

    public OrderSpecificationById(String id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfiedBy(Object order) {
        return ((Order)order).hasId(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Criterion toCriteria() {
        return Restrictions.eq("id", id);
    }
}
```

Then you must implment the logical specifications `AndSpecification`, `OrSpecification`, `NotSpecification`, etc..

AndSpecification.java

```
public class AndSpecification implements HibernateSpecification {
    private Specification first;
    private Specification second;

    public AndSpecification(Specification first, Specification second) {
        first = first;
        second = second;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfiedBy(Object candidate) {
        return first.isSatisfiedBy(candidate) && second.isSatisfiedBy(candidate);
    }

     @Override
    public Criterion toCriteria() {
        Conjunction conjuntion = Restrictions.conjunction();
        conjuntion.add(first.toCriteria());
        conjuntion.add(second.toCriteria());

        return conjuntion;
    }
}
```

OrderRepository.java

```
public List<Order> query(HibernateSpecification specification) {    
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Order.class);
    criteria(specification.toCriteria());
    return criteria.list(); 
}
```

Comment: Except that he is not using any Hibernate specific code. If you rewrite in terms of JPA interfaces then probably the correct answer despite being essentially what was proposed below.

Comment: Sorry, you sent your message while I was answering. Yes, you are right, he can implement in terms of JPA interfaces in his case.